# $facebook->getUser() fails, but fb:login-button indicates that user is logged in

Tags: php, facebook, session, authentication

At some point, Facebook changed the behavior of the fbml login button so that it does not appear when the user is already logged into your website via FB.

That's all well and good, but I am running into a situation where the PHP SDK thinks that the user is not logged in, but the FBML button DOES think that the user is logged in, and as a result, it's not displaying itself.

Any ideas for how I might debug this further? This might be an edge case, but I need to fix it because users won't be able to log in when the FB button is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an update on what we have learned for anyone running into the same problem.

The problem appears to occur because we upgraded our Facebook PHP SDK to 3.1.1 from a previous version.

After tracing through the code, we learned that in the previous version of the FB PHP SDK, session state was stored in a cookie called fbs_. The new version of the SDK isn't able to restore the session from this cookie. Instead, it relies on a cookie called fbsr_ in order to store a signed request.

So if fbs_ is set a certain way, the fb:login-button thinks that you are logged in, but the 3.1.1 SDK does not think you are logged in.

We tried manually clearing the fbs_XXX cookie via code, but that cookie would be restored every time the fb:login-button did its thing. In the end, we ended up creating our own login button using $facebook->getLoginUrl(), which seems like the new way that Facebook wants you to do things anyway.